# Django Json saved in DB how to use in template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to save a Json data in DB and then display it in template.

Data is saved as:

```
{"reaction": [{"reactionmeddrapt": "Stress fracture", "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1", "reactionoutcome": "1"}, {"reactionmeddrapt": "Drug effect incomplete", "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1", "reactionoutcome": "6"}, {"reactionmeddrapt": "Osteoarthritis", "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1", "reactionoutcome": "3"}, {"reactionmeddrapt": "Fracture delayed union", "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1", "reactionoutcome": "6"}, {"reactionmeddrapt": "Knee arthroplasty", "reactionmeddraversionpt": "20.1", "reactionoutcome": "6"}], "drug": [{"medicinalproduct": "PROLIA", "drugindication": "PRODUCT USED FOR UNKNOWN INDICATION", "drugadministrationroute": "065", "drugdosagetext": "UNK, Q6MO", "openfda": {"manufacturer_name": ["Amgen Inc"], "unii": ["4EQZ6YO2HI"], "product_type": ["HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG"], "rxcui": ["993452", "993456"], "spl_set_id": ["49e5afe9-a0c7-40c4-af9f-f287a80c5c88"], "route": ["SUBCUTANEOUS"], "generic_name": ["DENOSUMAB"], "brand_name": ["PROLIA"], "product_ndc": ["55513-710"], "pharm_class_epc": ["RANK Ligand Inhibitor [EPC]"], "substance_name": ["DENOSUMAB"], "spl_id": ["f0a4aa32-b689-4a2a-b575-7b3156e79c0c"], "pharm_class_moa": ["RANK Ligand Blocking Activity [MoA]"], "application_number": ["BLA125320"], "nui": ["N0000187054", "N0000187055"], "package_ndc": ["55513-710-01"]}, "drugdosageform": "SOLUTION FOR INJECTION", "drugcharacterization": "1", "activesubstance": {"activesubstancename": "DENOSUMAB"}, "drugauthorizationnumb": "125320", "actiondrug": "5", "drugadditional": "3"}]}
```

In my view I converted this data using `json.loads(json_data)`

Now I am trying to iterate this in template but not able to do it.

I have tried with Json_data with json.loads and without json.loads. It does not seem to work.

I have tried every every thing in template `{% for key, value......` and directly `{{json_data.field_name}}`

It seems to be one of most asked question on SO and no specific answer till now.

Comment: Half-created examples aren't useful. Please give a concrete example of what data you are returning and how you try to process it in the template. What have you returned from your `views`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of the dictionary is fixed, why not loop through drug and reaction separately and print things in the template manually?

You can edit the HTML as you want. If some of these items are lists, you can loop through them as well. For example, I'm looping through the `drug.openfda.rxcui` in the following code snippet.

```
{% for drug in json_data.drug %}
    <p>Actiondrug: {{ drug.actiondrug }}</p>
    <p>Activesubstance: {{ drug.activesubstance.activesubstancename }}</p>
    <p>Drugadditional: {{ drug.drugadditional }}</p>
    <p>Drugadministrationroute: {{ drug.drugadministrationroute }}</p>
    <p>Drugauthorizationnumb: {{ drug.drugauthorizationnumb }}</p>
    <p>Drugcharacterization: {{ drug.drugcharacterization }}</p>
    <p>Drugdosageform: {{ drug.drugdosageform }}</p>
    <p>Drugdosagetext: {{ drug.drugdosagetext }}</p>
    <p>Drugindication: {{ drug.drugindication }}</p>
    <p>Medicinalproduct: {{ drug.medicinalproduct }}</p>

    <p>OpenFDA</p>

    <p>application_number: {{ drug.openfda.application_number }}</p>
    <p>brand_name: {{ drug.openfda.brand_name }}</p>
    <p>generic_name: {{ drug.openfda.generic_name }}</p>
    <p>manufacturer_name: {{ drug.openfda.manufacturer_name }}</p>
    <p>nui: {{ drug.openfda.nui }}</p>
    <p>package_ndc: {{ drug.openfda.package_ndc }}</p>
    <p>pharm_class_epc: {{ drug.openfda.pharm_class_epc }}</p>
    <p>pharm_class_moa: {{ drug.openfda.pharm_class_moa }}</p>
    <p>product_ndc: {{ drug.openfda.product_ndc }}</p>
    <p>product_type: {{ drug.openfda.product_type }}</p>
    <p>route: {{ drug.openfda.route }}</p>

    {# example of looping through a list #}
    <p>rxcui: {% for r in drug.openfda.rxcui  %}{{ r }}{% endfor %}</p>

    <p>spl_id: {{ drug.openfda.spl_id }}</p>
    <p>spl_set_id: {{ drug.openfda.spl_set_id }}</p>
    <p>substance_name: {{ drug.openfda.substance_name }}</p>
    <p>unii: {{ drug.openfda.unii }}</p>

{% endfor %}

{% for reaction in json_data.reaction %}
    {% for key, val in reaction.items %}
        <p>reactionmeddrapt: {{ reaction.reactionmeddrapt }}</p>
        <p>reactionmeddraversionpt: {{ reaction.reactionmeddraversionpt }}</p>
        <p>reactionoutcome: {{ reaction.reactionoutcome }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my project. Wish I could you all my points :)

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: Is there a way to get list items as paragraph instead of looping?